# is it possible for python unittest case be loaded with some self-defined argument in setUpClass?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am writing some python unittest cases and use setUpClass to start with, however, I like some user interface that can control the saving path for some intermediate result, something like following. It is not working though, but the idea is I have a report_path argument in setUpClass argument list, so in some way, when instantiate this class, the user could input his own path:

```
    class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
        @classmethod
        def setUpClass(cls, report_path=None):
            cls.s = cls.analyserfunction(....)
            if report_path is None:
                cls.report_path = something I defined by default
            else: 
                cls.report_path = report_path

        @classmethod
        def analyserfunction(cls, ...):

        def test_func(self):
            do something for self.s
```

And I use TestLoader() to run it, something like this

```
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(
        test01.MyTestCase)
    testRunner = unittest.TextTestRunner(
        stream=sys.stderr, descriptions=True, verbosity=2)

    testRunner.run(suite)
```

It works perfectly fine if I use the code above, but if naively do this

```
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(
        test01.MyTestCase(report_path = 'some path'))
```

it will fail, it seems that the test suite can only accept the test case class without any argument, not like the traditional class. Is there any way that can get through this, i.e, load MyTestCase(report_path = 'some path')?

Comment: the analyserfunction is also decorated by @classmethod, I forgot to type it up.

Comment: you can still edit your question